# foreach loop issue with custom fields

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I have [this](http://427design.com/newsite/ourwork/image-test/) bootstrap slider that doesn't seem to be grabbing the video links properly.

This is the code I have:

```
        <?php $myCarousel = get_order_field('projectdetails_image'); // use the Custom Group name 
        if( !empty( $myCarousel )) {
                foreach($myCarousel as $carousel){
                $myimg = get('projectdetails_image',1,$carousel);
                    if ( !$myimg ) {
                    $videos = get_order_field('video_vimeo');
                    foreach($videos as $video){
                        if ( get('video_vimeo',TRUE) ) {
                                echo "<div class='item active black'><div id='video-wrap'>";
                                echo get('video_vimeo',1,$video);
                                echo "</div></div>";
                        }
                        else {}
                        }   
                    }
                    if ( $myimg ) {
                        echo "<div class='item".( $counter == 0 ? ' active' : '' )."'>";
                        echo '<img src="';
                        echo $myimg;
                        echo '"/>';
                        echo "</div>";
                        $counter++;
                
                        $videos = get_order_field('video_vimeo');
                        foreach($videos as $video){
                            if ( get('video_vimeo',TRUE) ) {
                                echo "<div class='item black'><div id='video-wrap'>";
                                echo get('video_vimeo',1,$video);
                                echo "</div></div>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>
```

The bottom if statement is giving me problems:

```
if ( $myimg ) {
                    echo "<div class='item".( $counter == 0 ? ' active' : '' )."'>";
                    echo '<img src="';
                    echo $myimg;
                    echo '"/>';
                    echo "</div>";
                    $counter++;

                    $videos = get_order_field('video_vimeo');
                    foreach($videos as $video){
                        if ( get('video_vimeo',TRUE) ) {
                            echo "<div class='item black'><div id='video-wrap'>";
                            echo get('video_vimeo',1,$video);
                            echo "</div></div>";
                        }
                    }
                }
```

For some reason its outputting a `<div class='item black'>` after every `<div class='item'>`
whereas I would like it to output the `<div class='item black'>` only after all the `<div class='item'>`'s have been outputted.

I hope that makes sense.
If someone could just point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: have you tried moving the `for` loop?

Comment: I did. Perhaps Im not moving it to the right place?

Comment: Haha I moved it out of the other for loop and it worked!

Comment: No problem. I posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `for` loop outside of the outer `for` loop, which is causing it to be executed on every iteration.